# Can linux host mutiple websites with one domain's different third domains?

Tags: dns, server, raspberry-pi, vpn, vps

I recently made some projects on raspberry pi with linux Debian Jessie, and I am interested in porting forward websites hosted on raspberry pi to a domain I owned.

From what I learned, it is possible to make each individual website on raspberry link with configured port according to apache , for example /home/pi/html/website01 -> port 11235 website02 -> 11236 so that I can browse the websites in private network. However, the domain I have is managed by godaddy, they provide the Chain without port, so that I can't redirect one of my third level domain(ex dashboard.domain.com to my dynamic dns hostname xx.dtdns.net with the port.

Is there any possible way or idea to get it work? I am lack of knowledge of nameserver, but I have an idea that using vpn or vps to map users to my private network instead of godaddy domain manager. I have alreay built the openvpn with cert and pptp vpn on my raspberrypi. Is it possible or what's next step?

Thanks, please give me some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use Virtual Hosting in Apache on your Raspberry. Install Apache2 on PI with:

```
apt-get install apache2
```

Create a new conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available or use an existing one. Add the ports for different site directories:

```
<VirtualHost *:11235>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/w1

        <Directory /var/www/w1>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:11236>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/w2

        <Directory /var/www/w2>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

and then set Apache tolisten on the ports in the /etc/apache2/ports.conf file:

```
Listen 11235
Listen 11236
```

Restart the Apache service. You should now be able to browse both ports using the same ip address. If your ip was 111.111.111.111 then w1 directory on 111.111.111.111:11235 and 111.111.111.111:11236.

If your domain is pointing to a IP, you can use different hostnames without making change to DNS. If you domain was mydomain.com, you could instead add new virtual host names with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName w1.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/w1

   <Directory /var/www/w1>
    Options +Includes -Indexes +FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName w2.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/w2

   <Directory /var/www/w2>
    Options +Includes -Indexes +FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! Now I am hosting in total 8 websites (each 4 third level websites for one domain) all in raspberry pi.